# Entity Framework writing NULL to the DB

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity

I am using EF v 6.2.0. My issue is similar to the SOF question - [Entity Framework not claiming datetime.now is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511060/entity-framework-not-claiming-datetime-now-is-null). However, the proposed solution does not work for me.

```
buildDetail.BuildTime = epoch.AddMilliseconds(Double.Parse(buildTime)).ToLocalTime();
:
:
: // Other properties.    

ps.dbEntities.BuildDetails.Add(buildDetailT);

ps.dbEntities.SaveChanges();
```

On the SaveChanges() line, I get an exception

```
Inner Exception 2:
SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BuildTime', table 'BuildDetailsDB.dbo.BuildDetails'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The buildDetail.BuildTime property, when I hover over in debug, shows the value as **{3/29/2018 9:17:22 AM}** i.e. current date time. The datatype in Sql Server is datetime and the model I have generated from the database shows that this field has a return value of System.DateTime. So, I am frustrated as to why EF is trying to insert a null. In fact, if I allow nulls for this columns in the DB, that is exactly what it writes in that column - NULL.

The field in question is neither marked as Identity (both in model and db) nor Calculated. I have also updated the model from the Database and they are in sync.

Note: I have tried the DateTime.ParseExact and even an DateTime object converted from a string in the exact same format as expected in SQL Server i.e. "yyyy-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFF" with no luck and the same exception. eg.

```
buildDetailT.BuildTime = DateTime.Parse("2018-11-25 08:25:26.0000");
```

Comment: *"So, I am frustrated as to why EF is trying to insert a null."* Apparently EF thinks that the column is generated by database. I see you said it is not Identity or Calculated, but in fact it is (or EF think/has been told it is). When you open the designer and select the property in question, what do you see in the `StoreGeneratedPattern` in Properties window?

Comment: @Ivan - SCORE ! Thanks, that was the exact issue, it was set to Computed. I did not know that extra place that it could be set, I was only aware of the decoration methodology for setting this and I am sorry for my erroneous assertion that I had checked that it was neither Identity nor Calculated.